# View with model that has children that act as model for strongly typed partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a system consisting of main page that starts a form:

```
@model Stuvo_Intakeformulier.Models.CaterRequest

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="fooData", @class="form-horizontal", role="form"}))
        {
         <div id="generalInfo" style="display:none">
              @{Html.RenderPartial("Food", Model.foodInfo);}
         </div>

         <div id="studyInfo" style="display:none">          
               @{Html.RenderPartial("Drinks", Model.drinkInfo);}
               <input type="submit" value="Bevestigen">
        ....
```

using a parent model

```
public class CaterRequest
{
    public CaterRequest()
    {
        foodInfo = new Food();
        drinkInfo = new Drinks();
    }

   public Food foodInfo { get; set; }
   ....
```

And child models like this:

```
public class Food
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "BlaBla")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the partial view looks like this:

```
@model Stuvo_Intakeformulier.Models.Food

<div class="form-group">    
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.name, "Naam: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.name, null ,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.name)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Obviously when posting my model.foodInfo.name will be empty because of the fact that in my partial views the name attribute is `name` instead of `foodInfo.name`. I can solve this by changing `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.name..` with `@Html.TextBox('foodInfo.name'` but then I lose all the advantages of my strongly typed partial view (especially the client side validation, which is something I absolutely need to have).

I was wondering what the best solution to this problem would be? Is there an easy way to solve this? What is the cleanest solution?

Basically I want to bind the data from my strongly typed partial views to my model in my normal view, while still maintaining the strongly typed views and validation stuff.

Comment: So you tested this and Model.foodinfo.name is indeed null after posting?

Comment: Yes, except if I change it to Html.Textbox().

Comment: Do you have a typo in "public string foodInfo { get; set; }", it should be " public Food foodInfo { get; set; }"?

Comment: Ah, yes, its not shown, but I have it.

Answer (score 1):

We use `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor` template. Its clean and comes with all features you mentioned. We have working code that is quite similar to [this link](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/).

So in you example above, you will need to create a Food.cshtml that can contain similar to what you have:

```
@model Stuvo_Intakeformulier.Models.Food

    <div class="form-group">    
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.name, "Naam: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.name, null ,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.name)
                </div>
</div>
```

Above `Food.cshtml` file has to be placed into the “Shared/EditorTemplates/” folder.

Then in your main page you can call like:

```
 <div id="generalInfo" style="display:none">
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.foodInfo)
 </div>
```

As a aside, Do you have a typo in `public string foodInfo { get; set; }`, it should be `public Food foodInfo { get; set; }`?

Comment: Is a typo yes, it was late, I'll edit my question and try your solution asap. Looks like it would do the trick.