# Creating complex model in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'd appreciate if someone could help

I have one-to-many relationship: a `Customer` and his `Addresses`. I established all the dependencies and my `Customer` class has `ICollection<Address> Addresses`. 
The problem is when I create new Customer:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    Address addr = new Address();
    addr.Customer = customer;
    customer.Addresses.Add(addr);
}
```

And when I receive the model from my view in `HttpPost` method:

```
public ActionResult Create(Customer entity)
{
}
```

The `Customer` model is correct and filled with values, but its `Addresses` collection is empty. What am I doing wrong?

My view `Create.cshtml` (`model.CUSTOMER_NO` is the PK in `Customers` table):

```
@model DAL.Model.Customer
@using DAL.Model
@using CurrencyControl.Enums
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app-ui.js")"></script>
@{
    Layout = null;
    CCEntities context = new CCEntities();
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "mainPane", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "viewForm form-horizontal" }))
{
    <button type="submit" class="saveButton">Save</button>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CUSTOMER_NO, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FULL_NAME)
    @Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name("BRANCH").BindTo((SelectList)(new SelectList(context.Branches, "COMPANY_CODE", "COMPANY_NAME"))).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
    @Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name("RESIDENCE").BindTo(Display.EnumToSelectList(typeof(Residence), Model.RESIDENCE)).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name("COUNTRY").BindTo((SelectList)(new SelectList(context.Countries, "Alpha2", "NAME"))).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" }))
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().CITY)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().STREET)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail on your View? The issue likely lies there.

Comment: I see another way is to pass 2 models to the view (Customer, Address), and assign them to each other in HttpPost method.

Comment: DisplayFor and EditorFor template is the way to manage it better. I had answered similar question recently here, see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816431/view-with-model-that-has-children-that-act-as-model-for-strongly-typed-partial-v/24817545#24817545

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to input the first Address's City&Street

```
@model DAL.Model.Customer
@using DAL.Model
@using CurrencyControl.Enums
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app-ui.js")"></script>
@{
    Layout = null;
    CCEntities context = new CCEntities();
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "mainPane", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "viewForm form-horizontal" }))
{   
    {<button type="submit" class="saveButton">Save</button>}

    {@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CUSTOMER_NO, new { @class = "k-textbox" })}

    {@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FULL_NAME)}

    {@Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name("BRANCH").BindTo((SelectList)(new SelectList(context.Branches, "COMPANY_CODE", "COMPANY_NAME"))).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })}

    {@Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name("RESIDENCE").BindTo(Display.EnumToSelectList(typeof(Residence), Model.RESIDENCE)).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })}

    {@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name("COUNTRY").BindTo((SelectList)(new SelectList(context.Countries, "Alpha2", "NAME"))).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" }))}

    {@Html.Editor("Addresses[0].CITY")}

    {@Html.Editor("Addresses[0].STREET")}
}
```

otherwise you need to create EditorTemplate for Address, and use

```
{@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addresses)}
```

Comment: There is an error, because Addresses is of type ICollection<Address> and i cannot apply indexing with []

Comment: sorry still doesn't work. i guess Customer is your domain model, usually i will create another view model for display, and use AutoMapper to convert to the view model to domain model and vise versa

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the behavior of the default MVC model binder. Essentially, whilst it handles nested properties without issue, it does not handle collections anywhere near as well. In my experience, the simplest solution is to use an array within your model and iterate through it with a standard for loop.

In your case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Addresses.Length; i++) {
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addresses[i].CITY)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Addresses[i].STREET)
}
```

Doing so will then generate the correct name values in the corresponding inputs, allowing the model binder to correctly regenerate your collections on the server. If you are uncomfortable changing your model to use arrays, consider using a specialised view model instead.